# Gestionar inventario de una tienda fisica (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

les presento mi dilema:
Tengo una tienda fisica donde vendo desde aretes hasta ropa y estoy desarrollando un sistema para gestionar el stock de mis productos; mi problema esta en la manera en que almaceno mi data, por ejemplo para el tema de la ropa un producto se subdivide en 2 mas (tallas y colores) en cambio los shampoo's se subdividen en litros, luego estan los productos como aretes que son stock unico y peluches que tambien son stock unico. La pregunta es: como puedo almacenar esta informacion en mi base de datos?
Yo e pensado en lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto aplica para el caso de ropa, pero para los shampoo no sirve. de antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, por aquí te dejo una propuesta por si te ayuda a verlo desde otra perspectiva. Tal vez no sea la mejor opción, pero puede ser un comienzo para dar con algo que se ajuste a lo que necesitas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ésta sería la estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  producto varchar(255),
  stock float
  );
CREATE TABLE caracteristicas(
  id_caracteristica int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  caracteristica varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE poseen(
  id_posee int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_producto int,
  id_caracteristica int,
  valor varchar(31),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_producto) REFERENCES productos(id_producto),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_caracteristica) REFERENCES caracteristicas(id_caracteristica)
  );
```

Con estos datos de ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO productos (producto,stock) VALUES
  ('Shampoo',250),('Aretes',15),('Peluches',18),('Zapatos',5);
INSERT INTO caracteristicas (caracteristica) VALUES
  ('Litros'),('Composición'),('Talla'),('Color');
INSERT INTO poseen (id_producto, id_caracteristica, valor) VALUES
  (1,1,'2'),
  (2,2,'Plata'),
  (3,4,'Rosa'),
  (4,4,'Negro'),
  (4,3,'44');
```

El listado del stock podrías obtenerlo así:

```
SELECT producto,GROUP_CONCAT(valor) caracteristicas,stock
  FROM productos
  JOIN poseen USING(id_producto)
  JOIN caracteristicas USING(id_caracteristica)
  GROUP BY id_producto;
```

Y, para saber cuántos zapatos negros de la talla 44 tienes, podrías hacer algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM productos
  WHERE producto='Zapatos'
  AND id_producto IN (
    SELECT id_producto FROM (
        SELECT id_producto FROM poseen
          JOIN caracteristicas USING(id_caracteristica)
          WHERE (caracteristica='Color' AND valor='Negro')
      ) c1 JOIN (
        SELECT id_producto FROM poseen
          JOIN caracteristicas USING(id_caracteristica)
          WHERE (caracteristica='Talla' AND valor='44')
      ) c2 USING(id_producto)
  );
```